# How to handle csrf tokens during testing of a backend api

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, integration-testing, csrf

How do I handle `csrf` middleware functionality when running unit/integration tests? I have an Angular web app that sits in front of an Express backend API. All of the backend routes are mounted after the csrf middleware, so during tests, I always run into the `ForbiddenError: invalid csrf token` error. So, which of these seems more appropriate:

1. Do not enable the `csrf` middleware when `process.env.NODE_ENV=test`
2. Expose a separate endpoint specifically for test environments to
   retrieve a `csrf` token and include it with each `request`

**Example 1**:

*express.js*

```
const isProd = process.env.NODE_ENV === 'production';
const isTest = process.env.NODE_ENV === 'test';

if (!isTest) {
  app.use(csrf());
}
```

*myTest.js*

```
it('should make a PATCH request', function() {
  // this would not throw any `invalid_csrf` token errors
  return request
    .patch('SOME_URL')
    .expect(200, 'some data')
});
```

**Example 2**

*express.js*

```
const isProd = process.env.NODE_ENV === 'production';
const isTest = process.env.NODE_ENV === 'test';

// CSRF token. Angular needs it to be named 'XSRF-TOKEN'
app.use(csrf());
app.use((req, res, next) => {
  const _csrf = req.csrfToken();

  res.cookie('XSRF-TOKEN', _csrf, {
    secure: isProd,
    httpOnly: isProd
  });

  res.locals._csrf = _csrf;
  return next();
});

const router = require('./router')(app);
```

*router.js*

```
if (isTest) {
  app.use('/test/csrf', (req, res) => {
    res.json({
      csrfToken: res.locals._csrf
    });
  });
}
```

*myTest.js*

```
const app = require('./app');
const request = require('supertest')(app);

// helper
const cookies = (res) => {
  return res.headers['set-cookie'].map((cookies) => {
    return cookies.split(';')[0]
  }).join(';')
};

describe('example PATCH', function() {
  let response;

  // Use test endpoint to retrieve csrf token
  beforeEach(async () => {
    response = await request.get('/test/csrf');
  });

  // csrf token included (mimicking a client-side request), this will not throw an `invalid_csrf` token
  it('should make a PATCH request with a token', function() {
    return request
      .patch('SOME_URL')
      .set('Cookie', cookies(response))
      .set({
        'xsrf-token': response.body.csrfToken,
      })
      .expect(200, 'some data');
  });
})
```

So my question really is: which approach do I use when working with the `csrf` middleware when I have a backend api for my frontend Angular app?

Libraries used:

`csurf`: https://github.com/expressjs/csurf

`supertest`: https://github.com/visionmedia/supertest

Comment: If you want to **unit** test your backend, you should be able to mock your token.

Comment: It's more of an "integration" test I guess

Comment: @cusejuice did you manage to find how to integrate test a csrf protected api?

Answer (score 0):

Both methods work, however I also propose a method 3.

Since tokens in `csurf`(which is based on [csrf](https://github.com/pillarjs/csrf)) are not time sensitive, you can always use a pair of predefined secret + token for unit test.

```
const Token = require('csrf')
const token = new token()
const csrfToken = token.create('test')
console.log(csrfToken) // gaabrhn3--fmoXcOhmwoS6noe1TYvaDHzpYY
```

*myTest.js*

```
request
  .patch('SOME_URL')
  .set('Cookie', '_csrf=test')
  .set({
    'xsrf-token': 'gaabrhn3--fmoXcOhmwoS6noe1TYvaDHzpYY',
  })
  .expect(200, 'some data');
```